# Funções com parâmetros do tipo TextBox e Botões

Tags: c#

Tenho um programa que em determinado momento trabalha com a visibilidade de um objeto.
Estou criando uma função e não sei como fazer referência à objetos.

```
private void Visible(object x, object y, object z, object a) 
{    
    x.Visible = true;
    y.Visible = true;
    z.Visible = true;
    a.Visible = true;
}
```

Os `.Visible` ficam em sublinhado vermelho, antes eu estava fazendo manualmente, mas com função diminui a quantidade de linhas de código.
Como faço pra fazer a referência a `TextBoxes` e `Buttons`?

Comment: podes explicar melhor? E melhora se possível a parte do código...

Comment: Por exemplo , eu quero ao clicar em um botão ele vai mostrar +4 botões .

Comment: Eu tenho vários botões com a mesma função de alterar a visibilidade de outros 4 , então para diminuir a quantidade de códigos eu preciso fazer a função , dentro dessa função eu passo os paramêtros , que no caso seriam os componente , Por exemplo " Visibilidade (textBox1,Botão1,Botão2,Botão3);

Comment: Estes parametros que eu passei é que serão mudados a visibilidade

Answer (score 8):

Todos os componentes que têm representação visual herdam da classe [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Altere o seu método para:

```
private void Visible(Control x, Control y, Control z, Control a) {

    x.Visible = true;
    y.Visible = true;
    z.Visible = true;
    a.Visible = true;  
}
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria , obrigado .

Answer (score 7):

Complementando a resposta do @ramaral, acho que esta é uma boa oportunidade para usar `params`.

```
private static void Visible(params Control[] controls)
{
    foreach(var control in controls)
        control.Visible = true;
}
```

Assim pode-se passar um numero variavel de controlos, e evitar a repeticao de codigo dentro do metodo `Visible`:

```
// uso
Visible(x, y, z, a);
```

[Mais informacao](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

Comment: Por acaso tinha pensado nisso mas tenho por principio, porque nem sempre sei o nível de conhecimentos do AP, pegar no código da pergunta e alterá-lo o menos possível para responder. Talvez fosse útil você acrescentar que assim é possível passar um qualquer número de parâmetros ao método.

Comment: @ramaral Concordo, também apoio respostas minimalistas, "*to the point*". A única situação em que elaboro mais a resposta, é quando acho que o OP está a tentar resolver o problema de forma errada, e então sugiro uma abordagem completamente diferente. Acho que esta vez foi uma excepção à minha regra ^^

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está tentando definir a propriedade em um objeto do tipo `object`, e não `TextBox`.

Você tem que fazer o `cast` para o tipo que você quer, por exemplo:

```
((TextBox)x).Visible = true;
```

ou

```
((Button)y).Visible = true;
```

Comment: A resposta de cima resolveu , obrigado pela atenção